# SPSS won't open dataset in Python

Tags: python, dataset, spss

I'm trying to manipulate SPSS datasets using a python script. The problem is, my code won't open the active dataset. The problematic part is this:

```
spss.StartDataStep()                     
dataset = spss.Dataset()
print len(dataset.cases)
```

This code will create a datasetobject if I manually open a .sav file and run the code. But in my program, it simply creates an empty dataset, even though I clearly have an active dataset running. How do I fix this?

Here's the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<string>", line 128, in <module> 
ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0`

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import SpssClient,spssaux, spss, os
SpssClient.StartClient()
path='c:\users\myDocs\'

def inlezen(path,filename):
            if filename.startswith("Dec_gemeente"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-3 A4   Label1 4-33 A30'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_post"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-3 A4   Label1 4-27 A24   Code2 28-32 A5  Label2 33-67 A35'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_etniciteit_kort"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-0 A1  Label1 1-23 A23'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_etniciteit_lang"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-1 A2  Label1 2-33 A32  Code2 34-34 A1  Label2 35-58 A24  Code3 59-59 A1  Label3 60-95 A36'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_geslacht"): 
                           vars= ' /1 Code1 0-0 A1  Label1 1-8 A8'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_landcode"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-3 A4  Label1 4-43 A40  Code2 44-44 A1  Label2 45-56 A12  Code3 57-58 A2  Label3 59-89 A31'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_nationaliteit"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-3 A4  Label1 4-43 A40  Code2 44-44 A1  Label2 45-56 A12  Code3 57-58 A2  Label3 59-89 A31'
            if filename.startswith("Dec_verbl"): 
                           vars=' /1 Code1 0-1 A2  Label1 2-84 A83'

            bestand=path+filename

            spss.Submit("""
            DATASET CLOSE ALL.
            GET DATA
            /TYPE=TXT
            /FILE='%s'
            /FIXCASE=1
            /ARRANGEMENT=FIXED
            /FIRSTCASE=1
            /IMPORTCASE=ALL
            /VARIABLES=%s.
            DATASET NAME LabelSet WINDOW=FRONT.
            DATASET ACTIVATE LabelSet.
            EXECUTE."""
            %(bestand,vars))



def wegschrijven(filename):

            labels1=''
            labels2=''
            labels3=''

            # Labels maken 1.
            varnaam=filename

            labels1='VAR LAB' + ' ' + varnaam + " '" + varnaam + "'" + '.' + '\n' + 'VAL LAB'+' '+varnaam
            for i in range(len(dataset.cases)):
               for j in range(2):
                  if j==0:
                     temp=str(dataset.cases[i, j])[2:-2]
                     labels1 = labels1 + '\n' + temp + ' '
                  if j==1:
                     temp=str(dataset.cases[i, j])[2:-2]
                     labels1 = labels1 + "'" + temp + "'"
            labels1=labels1+'.'


            try:
               # Labels maken 2.
               varnaam='test'
               labels2='VAR LAB' + ' ' + varnaam + " '" + varnaam + "'" + '.' + '\n' + 'VAL LAB'+' '+varnaam

               for i in range(len(dataset.cases)):
                  for j in range(2,4):
                     if j==2:
                        temp=str(dataset.cases[i, j])[2:-2]
                        labels2 = labels2 + '\n' + temp + ' '
                     if j==3:
                        temp=str(dataset.cases[i, j])[2:-2]
                        labels2 = labels2 + "'" + temp + "'"
               labels2=labels2+'.'
            except:
               labels2=''
               print 'geen var 2'

            try:
               # Labels maken 3.
               varnaam='test'
               labels3='VAR LAB' + ' ' + varnaam + " '" + varnaam + "'" + '.' + '\n' + 'VAL LAB'+' '+varnaam

               for i in range(len(dataset.cases)):
                  for j in range(4,6):
                     if j==4:
                        temp=str(dataset.cases[i, j])[2:-2]
                        labels3 = labels3 + '\n' + temp + ' '
                     if j==5:
                        temp=str(dataset.cases[i, j])[2:-2]
                        labels3 = labels3 + "'" + temp + "'"
               labels3=labels3+'.'
            except:
               labels3=''
               print 'geen var 3' 



            output= labels1 + '\n' + '\n' + labels2 + '\n' + '\n' + labels3
            print output

            # Output naar syntaxdoc schrijven

            NewSyntaxDoc = SpssClient.NewSyntaxDoc()
            NewSyntaxDoc.SetAsDesignatedSyntaxDoc()

            # Inhoud syntax wijzigen.
            NewSyntaxDoc.SetSyntax(output)

            # Syntaxdocument opslaan.
            pad='I:/geg/WON/1 cijfer/LABELS/spsfiles/Labelbestanden/'+filename+'.sps'
            NewSyntaxDoc.SaveAs(pad)




for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
      for filename in files:
          inlezen(path,filename)

          # Toegang krijgen tot data editor.
          spss.StartDataStep()                     
          dataset = spss.Dataset()
          print len(dataset.cases)


          # Wegschrijven labels naar .sps.
          wegschrijven(filename)  
          dataset.close()  
          spss.EndDataStep()             
END PROGRAM.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works fine for me (which gives a printback confirming there are 474 cases in the active dataset):

```
begin program.
import spss
spss.Submit(r"""
get file="C:/Program Files/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/Samples/English/Employee data.sav".
""")
spss.StartDataStep()                     
dataset = spss.Dataset()
print len(dataset.cases)
end program.
```

I would assume it is the line of code `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):` that is problematic in your code, in particular the files that it is picking and then subsequently trying to run the remaining code. Try debugging/assesing what files exactly are being looped over...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after a day of furious trying I came up with a workaround.

Apparently, the GET DATA command doesn't properly load the dataset into memory. I added a SAVE OUTFILE and GET FILE command and now it's working fine.

Here's my solution:

```
spss.Submit("""
            DATASET CLOSE ALL.
            GET DATA
            /TYPE=TXT
            /FILE='%s'
            /FIXCASE=1
            /ARRANGEMENT=FIXED
            /FIRSTCASE=1
            /IMPORTCASE=ALL
            /VARIABLES=%s.
            DATASET NAME LabelSet WINDOW=FRONT.
            DATASET ACTIVATE LabelSet.
            EXECUTE."""
            %(bestand,vars))

            spss.Submit("""SAVE OUTFILE ='c:\user\myDocs\TEMP.sav'.
            GET FILE ='c:\user\myDocs\TEMP.sav'.""")
```

This loads the dataset into memory properly. Still I think this is weird and unintuitive behaviour by SPSS. Thanks for your answer. It got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me too:

```
begin program.
import spss
spss.Submit(r"""

GET DATA 
  /TYPE=XLS 
  /FILE='C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\Samples\English\demo.xls' 
  /SHEET=name 'demo' 
  /CELLRANGE=full 
  /READNAMES=on 
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.

""")
spss.StartDataStep()                     
dataset = spss.Dataset()
print len(dataset.cases)
end program.
```

I tested with calling `GET DATA` with the Excel file open also and it worked fine. I'm not convienced it is `GET DATA`that is problematic in your code. I would test throughly a little more to ensure it works under all situations, your solution.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem in the original code is the unguarded expression  path='c:\users\myDocs\'  In Python, backslash expressions many indicate escape sequences and be converted to what they stand for, which will be unfortunate for a path.  Use forward slashes or precede with r as in path=r'c:\users\myDocs\'.  In this case you are lucky, but sooner or later you will get caught.

As for GET DATA, it will not read the entire file until necessary - an EXECUTE statement will force that to happen, but that should not affect the existence of the dataset.  However, the number of cases will not be known until the entire file is read.